# Why is array inserting null using map and each_slice

Tags: ruby

I want to slice and modify an array for now manually from [22,22] to [3,3] for example.

I am getting

> [nil, 3, nil]

output with the following code

```
def boom(array)

    array.map!.each_slice(2) do |a|
        a[0] = 3
        a[1] = 3 
        a[2] = 3
    end
    array
end

p boom([22,22, 22])
```

Not sure why a[1] gets replaced but now a[0] and a[2]

Comment: Why are you calling `each_slice`?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @squiguy This is just base code, I will need it to do other modifications to those three elements. I just don't understand why those assignments don't work as expected

Comment: Well, that's interesting.

Comment: @YuHao it should be [3,3,3]  why isn't that working properly?

Comment: It's like `map!` is taking the `.each_slice(2)` part as a block and not as a method concatenation. Doing `array.map!.each_slice(2) {|a| a[0] = 3, a[1] = 3, a[2]= 3}` I get `[nil, [3, 3, 3], nil]`. If I must say, you just found a bug. But I may getting ahead of myself.

Comment: @yeyo It’s not a bug. `x = 1, y = 2` is not the same as `x = 1; y = 2`, which is why you get a different result.

Comment: @yeyo, bugs are certainly discovered in Ruby from time-to-time, but it's pretty rare. When I see claims that certain behaviour is due to a Ruby bug, I am reminded of the oft-repeated phrase: "It can't be my code--it's got to be a hardware error". :-)

Comment: @AndrewMarshall nicely spotted, thank you.

Comment: @CarySwoveland hahahah well ... :), although, later I'll be asking a question about this behaviour, something isn't right for me.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it seems like you want to modify the original array in chunks of 3 elements; `map!.with_index` would allow you to use modulo to determine which position you are in:

```
def boom(array)
    array.map!.with_index do |el, idx|
      if idx % 3 == 0
        3
      elsif idx % 3 == 1
        4
      else
        5
      end
    end
    array
end

boom([22, 22, 22]) #=> [3, 4, 5]
```

Drop in whatever you want for 3, 4, and 5, obviously.

Comment: The OP's question contains two issues: first, the use case: "I want to slice and modify an array for now manually from [22,22] to [3,3] for example." Then, the behavior of `map!.each_slice(2)`. This addresses the use case, but not the behavior of his method.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
def dynamic_value(a)
  # do something with a
end

def boom(array)
  array.map! do |a|
    dynamic_value(a)
  end
  array
end

p boom([22, 22, 22])
```

Comment: The thing is, 3 was just an example, let's say I need to assign dynamic variables to each of those 3 elements. Let's say sample a[0] = 3, a[1] = j #j will be coming from somewhere else, a[2] = k #k will be generated from somewhere before, etc..

Comment: Then change 3 to a method that give back the value. I updated the code based on your comment.